# Bluetooth mouse disconnects but only when on battery

Tags: 12.10, mouse, power-management, bluetooth, battery

I use a **Lenovo Thinkpad Bluetooth Laser Mouse** with my **Thinkpad x130e** and **Quantal**. It works without problems as long as the notebook is on AC-Power. When it runs on battery the mouse works for some minutes or half an hour an suddenly it stops working and I must reboot to get it work again.

What is different with the bluetooth connection when running on battery and can it be changed? I guess it must have something to do with power saving functions.

Thanks for your help.

PS: I just found `/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/usb_bluetooth.sh`.
This looks as if there could be the solution for the problem but I'm not good at reading such scripts.

Answer (score 2):

Well, to disable this script, disabled the execute bit, using:

```
chmod -x /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/usb_bluetooth.sh
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Had you a look at the skript? When I disable it as you dicribed will it always stay on one of it's states. Should I plug in AC and then disable it to prevent it from switching or doesn't it matter?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this bug is similar to the following:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1072234

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1065157

Something I've noticed is if we switch between sessions, mouse gets back to work fine. 
Try it:

1. Make sure mouse stops to work
2. Switch to another session performing: ALT + F1
3. Then, switch back to GUI session: ALT + F7

Mouse should work again.
(try it more than once if it doesn't work...)